# Makefile with distant (AWS S3) targets

Tags: makefile, amazon-s3, mapreduce

I would like to create a makefile where the targets and dependencies would not be local files but rather live in some AWS/S3 bucket.

Consider the following example that would simply copy a 'data_raw' files into 'obj1' and then 'obj2' (you would need to edit 'bucket' to some bucket you own and create some 'data_raw' file before running this):

```
# local, works fine
bucket = /tmp/test/
cp = cp

# remote, does not work
bucket = s3://bucket/test/
cp = s3cmd cp

all : $(bucket)obj2

$(bucket)obj2 : $(bucket)obj1
    $(cp) $(bucket)obj1 $(bucket)obj2

$(bucket)obj1 :
    $(cp) $(bucket)raw_data $(bucket)obj1
```

The error I get with this is:

```
makefile:9: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.
```

which is for:

```
all : $(bucket)obj2
```

I suspect that make does not understand remote URIs ("s3://xxx") at all.

All the example/documentation I could find seem to implicitly refer to local files for targets and dependencies. Extensive googling only yielded some seemingly unfinished ideas about creating ant tasks for s3 (http://code.google.com/p/awstasks/).

This is in the context of running several complex/intricate MapReduce jobs in Python.

I would rather use GNU make but will certainly consider alternatives.

I could always create some light local mirror of the remote targets but certainly there is a better way?

Thanks in advance!

Nic

Comment: Make is best at using files *there* to build files *here*. But this makefile doesn't look too bad; are you trying to reduce the complexity? Could you run Make from within the bucket?

Comment: The difficulty here probably lies in Make not accepting remote URIs as targets or dependencies. Am I missing something silly (escaping?)? What kind of URIs should Make be able to handle? I would imagine that it mostly needs to be able to test for existence and get a date, which S3 should support?

Comment: I don't know AWS/S3, but could you use a couple of local files as proxies, just to `touch` to indicate that the real files had been modified, and a `synch` target to bring them up to date with their primaries?

Comment: Yes, that's one avenue I suggested as the last line of my questions. It feels more like a workaround than a real solution. How deep is your knowledge of Make and its many equivalents? Do you know one that would natively support remote resources? For example could it be possible to provide some script that would overload the test for existence and freshness?

Answer (score 2):

One workaround that works is to mount the S3 bucket locally.

On Linux, fuse/[s3fs](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse) can probably be used. That might work on MacOS too, but appears to be really messy to install. I resorted to using the commercial software [transmit](http://panic.com/transmit/) instead (click 'mount as disk'). With that, the above example is functional for me with:

```
bucket = /Volumes/s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/test/
cp = cp
```

In this example we use 'cp' because 's3cmd cp' rejects local uris. In a (my) real-life example that command would be replaced by some python map-reduce script that would need the actual s3 input/output uris.

To keep things tidy, there should probably be one prefix variable ("/Volumes/s3.amazonaws.com/") to the locally mounted files (for Make to test existence/up-to-date-ness) and one prefix variable ("s3://") for the build command to point to the actual data (the data would be massaged by EC2 instances through mapreduce, we absolutely do not want to download everything locally).

Keep in mind that S3 is only eventually consistent. Also make sure that in order to test for existence and up-to-date-ness, the entire file does not get locally downloaded (in that case some dummy files should be used).

Hope that helps.

If anyone has a more direct approach (no local mounting) I'm interested.

Nic

Answer (score 0):

I like what you're looking for.  But I'd be surprised if this ever got built into the makefile and `make` itself; as you rightly pointed out the "Linux" way to do this is to find a way to mount S3 as a file system.

However, if you'll include "make-like", I'd recommend `rake` from the Ruby universe.  It's been a while since I used it in anger, but I recall it allowed you to write custom extensions so that your sources and targets *didn't* need to be on local file system.

I would switch *all* my make-files to rake-files if only Ruby was a little more prevalent on the kinds of systems I tend to work on (fairly bare EC2 and ECS systems with no admin rights).

Answer (score 0):

Make uses the filesystem to determine which targets it needs to build from which per-requisites.

Files and directories on S3 cannot be used as targets or pre-requisists, unless they are mounted on the file-system (perhaps using something like the already mentioned [`s3fs` FUSE](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse))

You can mount it as a part of your Makefile, something like this

```
BUCKET      = bucket-name
BUCKET_DIR  = /

s3:
    mkdir --parents $@
    findmnt $@ || s3fs $(BUCKET):$(BUCKET_DIR) $@

s3/foo: foo | bin
    cp $< $@
```

This creates the mount-point `s3`, if doesn't already exist. 
If it's not already mounted, use `s3fs` to mount on that directory.

Now you should be able to run Make using objects on S3.

NB: `$<` and `$@` in this case are just fancy Make variables for `foo` and `s3/foo` in this case, so it'll run `cp foo s3/foo`.

Be aware that there are probably other considerations that *should* be made regarding the consistency of the remote storage, problems that may occur around timing etc.